# Can I use a property of an instance to update other properties?

Tags: javascript, constructor, properties

I'm trying to update a property of a constructor based on other property values that are getting changed when a certain function fires.

I've tried to create a function as a property and I will still get the same result.

```
class Rps {
        constructor () {
            this.userChoice  
            this.appChoice 
            this.userPoints = 0
            this.pcPoints = 0
            this.score = `${this.userPoints} - ${this.pcPoints}`
            console.log(score)
            this.registeredChoice = []
        }

    }
```

After I call a function that increments the user and pc Points, the properties will be updated after i try to console.log() the new object but it will not be the same for the score. The value of the score will not change.

Comment: Nothing here is a property of the constructor function, they're all properties of the created instance.

Answer (score 0):

A getter is perfect for this:

```
class Rps {
    constructor () {
        this.userChoice  
        this.appChoice 
        this.userPoints = 0
        this.pcPoints = 0
        this.registeredChoice = []
    }
    get score() {
        return `${this.userPoints} - ${this.pcPoints}`
    }
}
```

Alternatively, don't just update properties of the object in that function you have, but call `setUser(points)` and `setPc(points)` methods that can update the `score` property.

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast feedback. It seems to work. I've noticed that you didn't set the instance's property in the constructor as I did above. My question is, can I still use that score in another function to render it?

Comment: @J.Doe You can still access `rps.score` (that's the point), you cannot set it any more as it is only computed when you access the property. There is no need to initialise it in the constructor, the getter is inherited from the prototype on all instances.